# Invalid IPA File Structure - The Payload directory must not contain the following file(s)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

When upload my app to AppStore status changes for "Invalid Binary". I give this message on my email:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "MYAPPNAMERUSTITLE". To process your delivery, the following issues
>   must be corrected:
>
> Invalid IPA File Structure - The Payload directory must not contain
>   the following file(s):
>
> MYAPPNAME.app.dSYM
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your DSYM file from your zip archive and try to upload your application again.
It's helped for me in same situation.

Comment: whats the location of DSYM file in package ??

Comment: An IPA file is just a [ZIP archive with a predictable structure](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IPA_File_Format). You can change the extension to ".zip" and extract it. Remove the dSYM file from that expanded directory and zip it back up. Rename that result back to ".ipa" and try submitting that as your upload again.